# TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default(...)(...).select2 is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

I want to use select2  jquery library in my react js web application

i am import jquery in index.html page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

here select2.js component

```
 import React,{useState ,useEffect,useRef, Component} from 'react';
 import $ from 'jquery';

export default class select2 extends Component
{
   
    componentDidMount() {
        $(this.refskills).select2();
      }  
    render() {
        return (
        <select className="multiple-skils" 
                name="datajobskills" 
                multiple="multipleskils"
                ref ='refskills'>
            <option value="1">HTML</option>
            <option value="2">JS</option>
            <option value="3">CSS</option>
        </select>
        );
    }
      
}
```

and I am using that import select2 component

```
import React,{useState ,useEffect,useRef} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import $ from 'jquery';
import Tags from '../services/select2'

const Dashboardcomponent = (props) =>
{ return (
    <div>
<select2></select2>
</div>
)
}
```

Comment: first of all you have to avoid the use of jquery library inside react if you want to use then you have to use jquery accessors like $('#someIDHere')

Comment: should we use jquery plugins or always use npm packages in react js?

Comment: jquery is a different library as React so you should try one of them at a time and if you are using React js then for helpers you can use any other modules available for Reactjs in npm

Comment: are you using `webpack` to bundle your code?

Comment: Yes I am use webpack ... please provide any solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like others have suggested in the comments, it's not best practice to use jQuery with React since jQuery manipulates the DOM directly and React is unaware of those changes. React only knows about it's own representation of the DOM within the virtual DOM so it's best to avoid using them together. If you want you can take a look at this package `react-select`(https://react-select.com/home) that does pretty much what you want but in a react way of doing things.

With that said, **if you need your solution to work**, instead of using the `jquery` package and importing it into the `DashboardComponent`, you could add it as a global script in your `index.html` - just like you've done with the `select2` script. Then you can use it like so in your `componentDidMount` method - `window.$(".multiple-skils").select2();`

Here's working example - https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-greider-koezs?file=/src/select2.js:120-158

Comment: Did you add jquery to your index.html? Like here - https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-greider-koezs?file=/public/index.html:618-801

Comment: It's showing error ```TypeError: window.$ is not a function``` but I use setTimeout function then it's work good

Comment: Now I convert component to functional component and place script in useEffect now it's work .. thank you @ultimoTG